# customize query in post carousel(in elementor)

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have post type called "videos". each "videos" has a producer. In a page I need to have something like post carousel design which I can show only videos from a specific producer. for example I want to show videos for producer A only. unfortunately in "post carousel " widget,  only source( which is my post type) and "author" and "exclude" are shown and I can not limit the query.
is there any solution or alternative widgets in Elementor?